# python parsing json response

Tags: python, json

I'm a newb with JSON and am trying to understand how to parse a JSON response. In the example below, I'd like to know how to retrieve the value of 'issueId':'executions':'id'? in the example below it is '8195'.....

```
r = requests.get(baseURL + getExecutionsForIssueId + id, auth=('user','pass'))
data = r.json()


JSON Response:
    {
        "status": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "color": "#75B000",
                "description": "Test was executed and passed successfully.",
                "name": "PASS"
             },
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "color": "#CC3300",
                "description": "Test was executed and failed.",
                "name": "FAIL"
            },
            "3": {
    .
    .
    .
        }
    },
    "issueId": 15825,
    "executions": [
        {
            "id": 8195,
            "orderId": 7635,
            "executionStatus": "-1",
            "comment": "",
            "htmlComment": "",
.
.
.
```

Comment: `data['issueId']`?

Comment: I just answered a question very similar that might help you [for more complex json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978428/how-do-i-start-pulling-apart-this-block-of-json-data/38979645#38979645). There's lots of examples for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` object is just a dictionary in Python. Access the values you need like so:

`data['executions']` yields an array of similar dictionary objects, assuming your `JSON` response is typed as you intended.

```
executions = data['executions']
order_id = executions[0]['orderId']
```

If you wish to loop over them to find the correct object with an `id` of 8195:

```
executions = data['executions'] # [{'id':8195,'orderId':7635,...}, {...}, ...]
for e in executions:
    if e['id'] == 8195: # e is the dict you want
        order_id = e['orderId']
```

Comment: I've changed the original question above to "I'd like to know how to retrieve the value of 'issueId':'executions':'id'? in the example below it is '8195'..... " . In order to accomplish this:
execution = data['executions']
execId = execution[0]['id']